# JMS without a queue

Tags: jms

I am not expert in JMS and recently came across a situation in my project where they wanted to use JMS to communicate between applications. Is it possible to make use of JMS without an underlying MQ software like Websphere MQ / TIBCO EMS to communicate asynchronously. My thinking is that just like we use JDBC API to speak to a physical Database product (like Oracle/DB2 DB) underneath, we would use JMS to speak to a physical queue. But my team says just JMS and no queue. Can anyone help me understand? We use Websphere 6.0 server and use spring framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Websphere Application Server have internal queues (they name it default queues i guess) and they have there own JMS implementation (not even the same JMS implementation of Websphere MQ). Maybe your team is planning to use that, so there is dedicated MQ Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct: JMS is solely an interface, it contains no implementation. The comparison with JDBC is quite fitting.

When using JMS you always need a JMS provider. A provider is the JMS implementation, which interfaces a message oriented middleware.

Most application servers have built in JMS providers, so maybe your team meant using JMS without an external provider.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make use of JMS without an underlying MQ software like Websphere MQ / TIBCO EMS to communicate asynchronously

This makes no sense. Few points to note -

1. JMS is just [specs](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr343/index.html). By specs you can imagine it as set of APIs/interfaces/ method signatures and governing rules.
2. There are various organization/companies that provide implementation of these APIs.Apache's ActiveMQ,IBM's Websphere MQ or TIBCO EMS are some of the examples.
3. Now when you say I want to use JMS then you need a JMS compatible server i.e server which understands the rules laid down by specs. This is generally know as MQ server and is provided by the provider.

> My thinking is that just like we use JDBC API to speak to a physical Database product (like Oracle/DB2 DB) underneath, we would use JMS to speak to a physical queue. But my team says just JMS and no queue

Two things to note here. When you say you want to use databases and JDBC APIs to communicate JMS comes no where in the picture. Please understand why JMS is used. In short it is used to transfer messages between two decoupled system. What storage type JMS server uses(and if it is configurable) will depend on the provider. Generally all have DB storage type and can be configured to use your DB.

Next JMS has two types of communications - `PTP(peer to peer)` which uses `queues` and `PUBSUB(publish subscribe)` which uses `Topics`. When you say you are using JMS everything boils down to either of these two and some of it's variants.Now when you say JMS without a queue perhaps your team meant using PUBSUB. But again it is not something you decide randomly and use it in your application. This decision is takes as per what your requirement is as both of them behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need queues/topics to use JMS.

Second (your team probably means not using WebSphere MQ because my team was saying the same thing)

This diagram in IBM's Red Book will fully answer your question (it is the same as WS6):

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247770.pdf
page 4.

[image: JMS Provider Components]

Probably what you will be using is the WebSphere Default Messaging Provider.